# ImageMagick can't handle mixed font rendering

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

This is an example from Imagemagick that will render the chinese characters in the file if using the ZenKaiUni font.

convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48 -font ZenKaiUni label:@chinese_words.utf8   label_utf8.gif

I have a situation where a Chinese font is mixed with English and would like to render it with the above command. Imagemagick is rendering the English text with "?" symbols. Is it possible to provide an English font also to the same command above or any other way to render the mixed languages text ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick is not a text editor and so its text functions are basic. Later versions come with [Pango](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango) and you may be able to use that.

Comment: Thanks ! Pango does work to handle multiple fonts. But there is another problem. The text is always appearing at the top and is of fixed size, 
 unlike caption: which fills the size provided. Here is the command line I am using  "magick -size 400x100 -gravity center -define pango:justify=true pango:"hello" out.png"

Comment: I am afraid that is life; you could check out the official Pango website and see if there are any other options. There are some more define options here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo